# What is this command line that appears in vim?

Tags: vim

Sometimes in vim I accidentally invoke this command line prompt:

[image]

What is this called? What keys call this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the Command History search pane. As the shortcut is `q:`, I often find myself there by accident too. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history has the full usage. `:q` will quit the pane, and return you to where you were.